# Как с иcпользованием PHP конвертировать xlsb в более удобоваримый формат, например xlsx или csv и т.д. или прочитать под линукс?

Tags: php, xlsx

Погуглив так и не нашёл решения вопроса в основном решения предлагаются использовать библиотеку easyXLS, но она как я понял работает через COM и по тому для линукс хостингов не годится. Я нашёл решение-костыль в виде библиотеки на питоне, чтобы запускать этот скрипт из PHP но оно возвращает какой то мусор в котором нормально отображается последнее слово последней ячейки в каждой строкеи

> Расширение XLSB - это файлы электронных таблиц в двоичном формате,
>   созданных в Microsoft Excel. XLSB файлы отличаются от стандартных
>   файлов (.XLSX) в формате Open XML, так как они хранят таблицу,
>   используя двоичный формат (BIFF12).

Comment: пришлось даже загуглить что за `xlsb` такой :D

Comment: @teran ну так облегчил бы остальным жизнь ;)

Comment: Боюсь, что только писать самому. Спека тут http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSB/[MS-XLSB].pdf

Comment: Я кажется нашёл способ , но сильно ограниченный, правда мне всё равно за день максимум 1 раз надо преобразовывать.
https://www.filezigzag.com/api так что мне пойдёт, но за спецификацию спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум два проекта есть на `github`. Правда на `python`. Но кто Вам мешает вызывать их из `php` через `exec` ? :)

https://github.com/galizin/xlsb2csv

https://github.com/orangethakkali/xlsb2csv

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я видел все эти решения, прежде чем задать данный вопрос я прогуглил все возможные варианты и каждый из них был не идеальным, так например вариант с питоном выводил строки с не верной кодировкой. Не знаю как сейчас обстоят дела (возможно подправили) ибо на данный момент мне данная задача не актуальна уже. Но возможно у кого-то будет аналогичная и кто-то поделится готовым вариантом решения в ответах и кому то ещё оное поможет помимо варианта писать самому с нуля.